# Excel - Change data format in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in one cell (for instance, ND(1.37)), and need to display it in a different way (ND<1.37).

Is there a quick and easy way to do this through a macro or short script?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I haven't tried too much yet (I am still somewhat new with Excel macros), but an example of what I am looking for is:

ND(494) to ND<494
ND(319) to ND<319
ND(2.19) to ND<2.19

In essence, I am trying to change the ND(###) to ND<###.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes, there probably is". Show us what you've tried so far and let us know where the problem is, exactly. A larger set of sample data and expected outcome would also be useful.

Comment: Just use replace.  replace the `ND(` with `ND<` and the `)` with nothing.

Comment: This looks like it could work!  Could you give me a quick example of how the formula could look?  So far I've done "=REPLACE(K16,1,3,"ND<")" and it does okay removing everything and displays the ND<, but no other info is displayed and I am attempting to keep the number.

Comment: I was saying use the replace wizard on the menu bar.  If you want to use a formula you will want SUBSTITUTE" `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"ND(","ND<"))`

Comment: Ditto with what @Scott Craner said, but if you don't care about getting it back to the old format you could even skip the formula and just use the replace feature in all Office programs. Select the column you're targeting and hit Ctrl + H

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what u need:

```
Sub test()
Dim a As String
Dim cell As Object
For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Select
    a = ActiveCell.Text
    ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(Replace(a, "(", "<"), ")", "")
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If *all* your cells contain `ND(something)`,
you can use

```
="ND<" & LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3),LEN(A1)-4)
```

If you have data that don’t match that pattern,
you’ll have to specify what results you want.